# React Router is Not working when using octa-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am using octa-react library for authentication here. I have also given the dependencies below. I'm trying to pass my config data to octa login page if its authenticated then redirect to admin page in the project. In terminal its not showing any error but when I run this code its showing me this error. I'm stuck with this from last three days.
[No routes matched location "/"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjPEb.png)
App.js

```
import React,{ PureComponent } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { OktaAuth, toRelativeUrl } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';
import { Security, LoginCallback, SecureRoute } from "@okta/okta-react";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import Home from "./Home";
import { allReducers } from "./redux/reducers";
import Loader from "./views/Common/Loader";
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
const oktaauth = new OktaAuth(config.oidc);
const store = createStore(
  allReducers,
  {},
  window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension()
);
const HasAccessToRouter = ({ data }) => {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const restoreoriginalUri = async (_oktaAuth, originalUri) => {
    history.replace(toRelativeUrl(originalUri || '/', window.location.origin));
  };
   return (
    <Security {...data.oidc} oktaAuth={oktaauth} restoreOriginalUri={restoreoriginalUri} >
      <SecureRoute path="/" exact element={ <Home data={data} />}/>
      <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/implicit/callback" element={LoginCallback} />
      </Routes>
    </Security>
  );
};
class App extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      response: {},
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSettingsFromFile();
  }
  getSettingsFromFile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${
          process.env.PUBLIC_URL
            ? process.env.PUBLIC_URL
            : `${window.location.origin}`
        }/settings.json`
      );
      localStorage.setItem("apiUrl", response.data.API_URL || "");
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        response: response.data,
        //dashboardtype:""
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        response: {},
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { response, isLoading } = this.state;
    if (isLoading) {
      return <Loader />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router
            history={browserHistory}
            basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL || "/admini"}>
            <Routes>
              <Route element={ <HasAccessToRouter data={response} /> } />
            </Routes>   
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import { useOktaAuth } from "@okta/okta-react";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DefaultLayout from "./containers/DefaultLayout/DefaultLayout";
// import Login from "./Login";
import { Spin, Button } from "antd";
import { isEmpty } from "lodash";
const Home = (props) => {
  const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authState.isAuthenticated) {
      // When user isn't authenticated, forget any user info
      setUserInfo(null);
    } else {
      oktaAuth.getUser().then((info) => {
        setUserInfo(info);
      });
    }
  }, [authState, oktaAuth ]); // Update if authState changes

  // redirect to okta login
  const login = async () => {
    oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {authState.isAuthenticated !== null && (
        <div>
          {authState.isAuthenticated && !isEmpty(userInfo) ? (
            <div>
            <DefaultLayout {...props} />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="spinner">
              <Spin tip="Loading..." />
            </div>
          )}
          {!authState.isAuthenticated && (
            <div>
              <p>Please login to access the portal.</p>
              <Button id="login-button" type={"primary"} onClick={login}>
                Login
              </Button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
        "@coreui/coreui": "^4.2.0",
        "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
        "@coreui/icons": "2.1.0",
        "@coreui/react": "^4.3.0",
        "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^6.7.6",
        "@okta/okta-react": "^6.5.0",
        "@okta/okta-signin-widget": "^6.5.0",
        "antd": "^4.21.7",
        "antd-password-input-strength": "^2.0.1",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
        "classnames": "^2.3.1",
        "core-js": "^3.23.5",
        "cross-env": "7.0.3",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
        "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "history": "^5.3.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
        "react-datalist": "^4.0.0",
        "react-datalist-field": "^20.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
        "react-idle-timer": "^5.4.1",
        "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-spinners": "^0.13.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
        "reactstrap": "^9.1.2",
        "redux": "^4.2.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
        "simple-line-icons": "^2.5.5"
    }
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any `Route` component rendering a `path="/"`. I do see some `SecureRoute` component using a `path="/"` prop. What is `SecureRoute`? Is it compatible with RRDv6? The `BrowserRouter` component also doesn't take a `history` prop, so double check what & where you are trying to use a custom `history` object/reference.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm updating this project to newer version. I removed SecureRoute ,  I did change all the things you mention but still its not working.

Comment: Your RRD code looks to be using a mix of both the v5 and v6 syntax. `useNavigate` returns a `navigate` ***function***, not a `history` object, so `history.replace(....)` in `HasAccessToRouter` seems very incorrect. RRDv6 also generally doesn't allow for custom route components. Any descendent routes that `HasAccessToRouter` is rendering should be rendered in the `Routes` component.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you so much. I'll change all Routing related code. one last question, Is there any problem in octa-react code??

Comment: Are you asking if I know of any issues in the `"@okta/okta-react"` package? No, none as I'm unfamiliar with it. You'd need to check the repo's issues for that. Regarding the "custom route components", I know RRDv6 prefers wrapper/layout components for authentication over custom `Route` components, it does an explicit invariant check for this, but *some* modules have seemed to find a way around this though and I've not ever been bothered enough by it to go dig through their source to see how it was done.